# slow wampserver on localhost

Tags: localhost, wampserver, freeze, lag

I have setup a local development environment in my pc for joomla sites. Installed wampserver 3.0.6 (apache 2.4.23, PHP 5.6.24, 7.0.10, 7.0.20, and MySql 5.7.14.) localhost is ok I can see the wampserver   server configuration page. I set 3 virtual hosts ok and they did work fine for a couple of days. 
In one of them I installed Favourite theme and things got slow but not stuck yet. 
With difficulties and delays i installed Virtuemart there too and configured it, added a couple of categories and products slowly but ongoing. 
I was configuring main menu module in nav position and google when chrome began to freeze. i change the position and it works, slowly but works, back to nav position and chrome stalls. Wampserver green all the time. In firefox things get slow but I can still work and waiting for localhost tends to be 10 to 20 seconds per save or refresh.
Now if I set main menu module somewhere else, the site works but i get timeouts all the time or the site freezes altogether so working in it is very frustrating and time consuming.
I can't seem to work it around. 
Can somebody help me with correct and thorough troubleshooting and corresponding configuration PLEASE? txs in advance, Eugenio

Comment: This sounds like too much software and not enough mechine to runn it on. Or no attempt to configure MySQL to suite your applications needs!

Comment: so...?  can you help? What should I do about MySql? Is your commento only a critique?

Comment: First thing to try. Instead of using `localhost` in your database connections in the PHP code, try using `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Are your tables MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: Have you considered some Database optimisation? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb.html MySQL Server is a complex tool. One configuration does not always suit all situations

Comment: Thak you. How is the databes connection modified? only in configuration.php file?  change localhost =>127.0.0.1 there?
My tables are INNODB. will look into database optimization right know.

Comment: Can't this problem be troubleshot from within the loggs? where what to look for? I've seen a lot of calls to ::1 and 127.0.0.1. Sounds strange . I would expect to work on IPv4 or IPv6 but no either one... still not sure about it. Logs SHOULD be the starting point. Help?

Comment: Look at the wampmanager menus to access the logs og Apache/PHP and MySQL